# Select from two tables and set null column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables

Schedule:

```
scheduleID    DriverID      ScheduleDate
11            1             2015-05-20
22            2             2015-05-20
33            NULL          2015-05-21
44            NULL          2015-05-21
```

and

Employee:

```
ID           Fname          Lname
1            jack           miller
2            kelly          moore
3            mark           sam
4            tom            hanks
```

I want to select from these two tables based on ScheduleDate and show the driver full name from Employee table and show null columns.

The result should be like:

```
scheduleID    Fname       Lname
33            NULL         NULL
44            NULL         NULL
```

I used:

```
select  row_number() over (order by scheduleID desc) as schedule, scheduleID, Driver_ID,FirstName,LastName
From Schedule, Employee
where scheduleDate= '2015-05-21' AND EmployeID=Driver_ID;
```

It works well if " scheduleDate= '2015-05-20' "

but I need to show null Columns too!
any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `left join` for this -- just emphasizing why you should never using implicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Always* use explicit `join` syntax.  Never use commas in the `from` clause.

```
select row_number() over (order by scheduleID desc) as schedule, scheduleID, 
       Driver_ID, FirstName, LastName
From Schedule left join
     Employee
     on EmployeID = Driver_ID
where scheduleDate = '2015-05-21';
```